# bsnl broadband high data usage

Tags: internet, broadband

Recently I found that the `BSNL broadband` data usage is very high. I'm not downloading anything big. One instance is when I just used the internet for checking mail and found that the data downloaded for that session close to 4MB. Strange. And I did not download any attachments during that session.

I found these numbers from the **BSNL selfcare portal**

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check what is consuming your data is to find out which processes are connected to Internet. 
While it is not mentioned here which OS does the asker uses, solution for Windows 7 and Linux is provided below :

**For Windows 7**:

- Press `Win` key, Type `Resource Monitor`, Open it.
- Below the Menu Bar, there will be five tabs, click on `Network`.
- In the Section `Process with Network Activity`, you can see all the processes connecting and consuming data from the Internet. You can end any process by selecting it, **Right-Click** and Choose `End Process`.

**For Linux**:

- Open `Terminal`, type the command `netstat -abn`.
- It will list all the processes connecting to Internet. You can kill any process by selecting  its **PID** and typing command `kill process_pid` where **process_pid** is the PID selected.

Additionally, to monitor bandwidth usage in Linux, tools like **Nethogs** can be used. 
**About Nethogs** : `Net top tool grouping bandwidth per process`. 
 
 
**Description**:`NetHogs is a small 'net top' tool. Instead of breaking the traffic down per protocol or per subnet, like most such tools do, it groups band-width by process and does not rely on a special kernel module to be loaded. So if there's suddenly a lot of network traffic, you can fire up NetHogs and immediately see which PID is causing this, and if it's some kind of spinning process, kill it.`

**Relevant Usage**: After installing Nethogs, in the `Terminal` type the command `nethogs interface` where **interface** is the **Network interface** you want to monitor. For Wired Connectivity it is typically **eth0** but all interfaces can be listed by issuing the command `ifconfig`.